# How to solve a special equation: $g''=1-x+(xg')^{2/3}$ with certain boundary conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Recently, I met a special equation $$g''=1-x+(xg')^{2/3}$$ with boundary condition $g(0)=0, g'(0)=0$. Can we solve the ODE explictly? or at least find an approximated solution? I even don know which kind of ODE it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=g'$ ,

Then $u'=g''$

$\therefore u'=1-x+(xu)^\frac{2}{3}$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=1-x+x^\frac{2}{3}u^\frac{2}{3}$

Let $v=u^\frac{1}{3}$ ,

Then $u=v^3$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=3v^2\dfrac{dv}{dx}$

$\therefore3v^2\dfrac{dv}{dx}=1-x+x^\frac{2}{3}v^2$

Let $v=\dfrac{1}{w}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dx}=-\dfrac{1}{w^2}\dfrac{dw}{dx}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{3}{w^4}\dfrac{dw}{dx}=1-x+\dfrac{x^\frac{2}{3}}{w^2}$

$\dfrac{dw}{dx}=\dfrac{(x-1)w^4}{3}-\dfrac{x^\frac{2}{3}w^2}{3}$

This belongs to a "Chini-like" equation as [mentioned here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor/Chini) and which is more complicated than Abel equation of the first kind.

I still don't know whether existing a substitution so that $w^2$ term can be eliminated and keeping $w^3$ term still vanished, leading it exactly belongs to a Chini equation.

It still don't know whether existing method can solve Chini equation generally, while Abel equation of the first kind eventually can be solved generally starting in 2011 August, see [this](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2) for details.